# Python: Unknown Syntax Error (easy)

Tags: python

I'm getting a syntax error around the word rental and I just have no clue what I've done wrong. This is like my 6th program. Any and all suggestions are helpful.

```
#Computes Cable Bill

print("Welcome to cable customer billing calculator")
acct = int(input("Enter an account number"))
cust_type = input("Enter customer type: (R) Residential or (B) Business: ")

def residential():
    processing = 4.50
    basic_service = 20.50
    daily_rental = 2.99
    prem_channel_fee = 7.50
    prem_channels = int(input("Enter the number of premium channels used: ")
    rental = int(input("Were movies rented (Y or N): ")
        if rental == Y or y:
            rental_days = int(input("Enter the total number of rental days (one day for each movie, each day): ")
        else:
            rental_days = 0
    bill_amt = processing + basic_service + (rental_days * daily_rental) + (prem_channels * prem_channel_fee)
    return (bill_amt)

def business():
    processing = 15
    basic_service = 75
    prem_channel_fee = 50
    connections = int(input("Enter the number of basic service connections: ")
    prem_channels = int(input("Enter the number of premium channels used: ")
        if (connections <= 10):
            bill_amt = processing + basic_service + (prem_channel * prem_channel_fee)
        else:
            bill_amt = processing + basic_service + ((connections - 10) * 5) + (prem_channel * prem_channel_fee)
    return (bill_amt)

if (cust_type == "R" or "r"):
    bill_total = residential()
else:
    bill_total = business()

print("Account number: ", acct)
print("Amount due: ",bill_total)
```

Comment: can you print the error message?

Comment: Please don't fix the code of your question.  It makes the answers not make sense.  I rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add closing parentheses as depicted in the snippet below and ensure that the first line of your conditionals line up with the previous line. Also, consider matching the value of `rental` against a list of valid responses – it's more Pythonic way of writing the logic you're proposing:

```
prem_channels = int(input("Enter the number of premium channels used: "))
rental = int(input("Were movies rented (Y or N): "))
if rental in ['Y', 'y']:
    rental_days = input("Enter the total number of rental days (one day for each movie, each day): ")
```

Similarly, the following lines need closing parentheses:

```
connections = int(input("Enter the number of basic service connections: "))
prem_channels = int(input("Enter the number of premium channels used: "))
```

Replace the logic of your final conditional as above:

```
if (cust_type in ["R", "r"]):
```

Or, alternatively (but less Pythonic):

```
if (cust_type == "R" or cust_type == "r"):
```

Finally, note that `input("Were movies rented (Y or N): ")` returns a string and thus should *not* be cast to an integer. If you cast it using `int()`, you'll receive a type error and `if rental in ['Y', 'y']:` will never evaluate to `true`.

Comment: i employed your suggestions and updated the code. any ideas on the syntax error about the first else statement?

Comment: Please update your question to include the actual error you're receiving.

Comment: I dont have a debugger-it's just "Syntax error" and it highlights the first else. I apologize-is there a way to give you more information?

Comment: Did you add a closing parentheses to the line preceding `else`?

Comment: I got all the bugs worked out. Stupid shit really, which makes me even more thankful for your time and help with this noob.

Comment: Glad it helped... was there anything I was missed in my above explanation?

Answer (score 1):

```
if rental == 'Y' or rental == 'y':
```

Should solve this

Answer (score 1):

Following should help you.

```
rental = str(input("Were movies rented (Y or N): "))
if rental == "Y" or rental == "y":
```

Points raised by [zeantsoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1086529/zeantsoi) are also valid. Please consider them too.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of errors:

- `prem_channels = int(input("Enter the number of premium channels used: ")` needs closing parenthesis.
- `rental = int(input("Were movies rented (Y or N): ")` remove `int(`.  The input is a string.
- `if rental == Y or y:` should be `if rental == 'Y' or rental == 'y':`.
- The whole `if rental` block needs unindented to line up with the previous line.
- The two lines below need trailing `)`:

  > connections = int(input("Enter the number of basic service connections: ")
  >   prem_channels = int(input("Enter the number of premium channels used: ")
- The `if (connections` block needs unindented to line up with the previous line.
- `if (cust_type == "R" or "r"):` should be `if cust_type == 'R' or cust_type == 'r':`
- The `bill_amt` calculations both need to use `prem_channels` not `prem_channel`.

In addition, parentheses around if statements and return values are unnecessary.

Here's your code with the above fixes:

```
#Computes Cable Bill

print("Welcome to cable customer billing calculator")
acct = int(input("Enter an account number"))
cust_type = input("Enter customer type: (R) Residential or (B) Business: ")

def residential():
    processing = 4.50
    basic_service = 20.50
    daily_rental = 2.99
    prem_channel_fee = 7.50
    prem_channels = int(input("Enter the number of premium channels used: "))
    rental = input("Were movies rented (Y or N): ")
    if rental == 'Y' or rental == 'y':
        rental_days = int(input("Enter the total number of rental days (one day for each movie, each day): "))
    else:
        rental_days = 0
    bill_amt = processing + basic_service + (rental_days * daily_rental) + (prem_channels * prem_channel_fee)
    return bill_amt

def business():
    processing = 15
    basic_service = 75
    prem_channel_fee = 50
    connections = int(input("Enter the number of basic service connections: "))
    prem_channels = int(input("Enter the number of premium channels used: "))
    if connections <= 10:
        bill_amt = processing + basic_service + (prem_channels * prem_channel_fee)
    else:
        bill_amt = processing + basic_service + ((connections - 10) * 5) + (prem_channels * prem_channel_fee)
    return bill_amt

if cust_type == "R" or cust_type == "r":
    bill_total = residential()
else:
    bill_total = business()

print("Account number: ", acct)
print("Amount due: ",bill_total)
```